# how to call or start include space name file in cmd or batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I call or start non space name file in batch codes:

```
start c:\tenone.mp3
```

it is easy to call.

```
start c:\ten oness.mp3
```

"ten space oness.mp3" how to call? Cannot call ten oness.mp3

Note:  .mp3 is exist two files (tenone, ten oness)(i cannot call 'ten oness.mp3' how to call).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Code lines only need to be indented 4 spaces to be formatted as code, not 40, and there's no need to leave 10 blank lines before and after paragraphs. :-)

Comment: It's nice to use the `accept` tick and `upvote` good answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
start "" "c:\ten oness.mp3"
```

You need the `""` because start takes the first parameter in DoubleQuotes as title